# Using PHP/MySQL to automate email campaign, not sure how to structure query

Tags: php, mysql, email, sendgrid

I have two MySQL tables, one with subscriber details, the other where I keep track of who has had an email sent to them, which campaign, which version, etc (crawler and sent_mail, respectively.) I've built a script which can go through the crawler table and send emails based on the SendGrid API, a web form and some javascript. But I am trying to figure out how I can tell the script to pull emails from the crawler table which don't have the current campaign listed in the sent_mail table. I know I have to use a join, but am not really sure how to build the logic into the query. Thoughts? My attempt follows below:

```
foreach ('SELECT crawler.email FROM crawler LEFT JOIN sent_mail ON crawler.email = sent_mail.email WHERE sent_mail.campaigns <> "$campaign"') as $address) as $address) {
    $email = new SendGrid\Email();
    $email
        ->addTo($address)
        ->setFrom($address)
        ->setSubject($title)
        ->setText($text)
        ->setHtml($text)
    ;
    $sendgrid->send($email);
    $db-> $query = "
          INSERT INTO sent_mail (email, campaigns, campaign_version)
          VALUES ($address, $campaign, $campaign_version)"; echo 'great success';
}
```

Comment: What application or database framework are you using here? Generally using string interpolation is a sign you're doing something severely wrong because you're not [escaping those variables](http://bobby-tables.com/php) properly.

Comment: I'm just writing this in vanilla PHP, with MySQL accessed via PDO. It's running on my local server, not available to the internet at large, so I didn't worry about SQL injection.

Comment: Don't be casual about this. It's not hard to do it correctly using PDO, and it'll save you the potentially company-destroying mistake that might happen if this code gets put into production somehow. There's honestly no excuse for how sloppy you're being here. [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) are really easy to write. What you're doing here will fail the instant someone puts a quote in any of those strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the below code..
i think the below code might help a bit

```
    $get_records = mysql_query('SELECT crawler.email as `email_val` FROM crawler LEFT JOIN sent_mail ON crawler.email = sent_mail.email WHERE sent_mail.campaigns <> "$campaign"');

$i = 1;
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_records)){

    $to = $data['email_val'];
    $subject = 'Your Subject';

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: Your Name <you@you.com>' . "\r\n";


    $sendmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if($sendmail){
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sent_mail (email, campaigns, campaign_version)
          VALUES ('your value', 'your value', 'your value')");
        if($insert){
            echo  $i.'Value inserted & Mail sent to'.$data['email'];
        }else{
            echo  $i.'Value not inserted but Mail sent to'.$data['email'];
        }
    }else{
        echo  $i.'Mail sending fail to'.$data['email'];
    }
$i++;
}
```

Note: Before running the above code make sure you have established database connection.

Comment: I should have been clearer-if a given email has already been hit in a given campaign (meaning the campaign is in the sent_mail table entry for that email,) I don't want it to be emailed again.

Comment: for that you have check in db by SELECT query... Now i am changing my code assuming that you have passed correct value in your $campaign and you have given correct table names & fields

Comment: What the heck is `mysql_query` doing here?